# How to add column to a data.table in R that is based on a string in another column?

Tags: regex, r, parsing, transform, data.table

I would like to add columns to a data.table based on a string in another column. This is my data and the approach that I have tried:

```
                                                                                     Params
1:                                   { clientID : 459;  time : 1386868908703;  version : 6}
2: { clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ea8b534b2b0b5000575f;  time : 1386868824339;  user : 459001}
3:                                                 { clientID : 988;  time : 1388939739771}
4: { clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ec00b73cbf0b210057e9;  time : 1386868810519;  user : 459001}
5:                                                 { clientID : 459;  time : 1388090530634}
```

Code to create this table:

```
DT = data.table(Params=c("{ clientID : 459;  time : 1386868908703;  version : 6}","{ clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ea8b534b2b0b5000575f;  time : 1386868824339;  user : 459001}","{ clientID : 988;  time : 1388939739771}","{ clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ec00b73cbf0b210057e9;  time : 1386868810519;  user : 459001}","{ clientID : 459;  time : 1388090530634}"))
```

I would like to parse the text in the "Params"-column and create new columns based on the text in it. For example I would like to have a new column named "user" that only holds the number after "user:" in the Params string. The added column should look like this:

```
                                                                                     Params          user
1:                                   { clientID : 459;  time : 1386868908703;  version : 6} NA
2: { clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ea8b534b2b0b5000575f;  time : 1386868824339;  user : 459001} 459001
3:                                                 { clientID : 988;  time : 1388939739771} NA
4: { clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ec00b73cbf0b210057e9;  time : 1386868810519;  user : 459001} 459001
5:                                                 { clientID : 459;  time : 1388090530634} 459001
```

I created the following function to parse (in this case for the "user"):

```
myparse <- function(searchterm, s) {
  s <-gsub("{","",s, fixed = TRUE)
  s <-gsub(" ","",s, fixed = TRUE)
  s <-gsub("}","",s, fixed = TRUE)
  s <-strsplit(s, '[;:]')
  s <-unlist(s)
  if (length(s[which(s==searchterm)])>0) {s[which(s==searchterm)+1]} else {NA}
}
```

Then I use the following function to add a column:

```
DT <- transform(DT, user = myparse("user", Params))
```

This works in the case of "time" which is included in all the rows but does not work in the case of "user" which is only included in two of the rows. The following error is returned:

```
Error in data.table(list(Params = c("{ clientID : 459;  time : 1386868908703;  version : 6}",  : 
  argument 2 (nrow 2) cannot be recycled without remainder to match longest nrow (5)
```

How can I address this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to use regular expressions for this task:

```
myparse <- function(searchterm, s) {
  res <- rep(NA_character_, length(s)) # NA vector
  idx <- grepl(searchterm, s) # index for strings including the search term
  pattern <- paste0(".*", searchterm, " : ([^;}]+)[;}].*") # regex pattern
  res[idx] <- sub(pattern, "\\1", s[idx]) # extract target string
  return(res)
}
```

You can use this function to add new columns, e.g., for `user`:

```
DT[, user := myparse("user", Params)]
```

The new column contains `NA` for the rows with no `user` field:

```
DT[, user]
# [1] NA       "459001" NA       "459001" NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine for the data that I have provided. How would I need to adjust the regex to also allow for strings like "{ clientID : 461; time : 1386770861254; type : new; newUser : 461002}", which include something like the "type:new"?

Comment: @Miriam What should be the result for this example, `"type:new"` or `"new"`?

Comment: The column should be named "type" and the value "new" (like user:"459001" above).

Comment: @Miriam Try `DT[, type := myparse("type", Params)]`.

Comment: For some reason that I dont know this does not work if you use our myparse function with my string:`> t <- "{ clientID : 461; time : 1386770861254; type : new; newUser : 461002}"
> myparse("type", t)
[1] "{ clientID : 461; time : 1386770861254; type : new; newUser : 461002}"`The whole string is returned in contrast to myparse("time", t). Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: @Miriam I updated the function. Now it works with nondigit characters too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some external parser, for example:

```
library(yaml)

DT = data.frame(
    Params=c("{ clientID : 459;  time : 1386868908703;  version : 6}","{ clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ea8b534b2b0b5000575f;  time : 1386868824339;  user : 459001}","{ clientID : 988;  time : 1388939739771}","{ clientID : 459;  id : 52a9ec00b73cbf0b210057e9;  time : 1386868810519;  user : 459001}","{ clientID : 459;  time : 1388090530634}"), 
    stringsAsFactors=F
    )

conv.to.yaml <- function(x){
     gsub(';  ','\n',substr(x, 3, nchar(x)-1))
}

tmp <- lapply( DT$Params, function(x) yaml.load(conv.to.yaml(x)) )
```

then combine the parsed lists into data frame:

```
unames <- unique( unlist(sapply( tmp, names) ) )
res <- as.data.frame(  do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, function(x)x[unames]) ) )
colnames( res ) <- unames
res
```

the result is pretty much close to what you have in mind, but you need to think about better handling for the time values:

```
> res
  clientID       time version                       id   user
1      459 -405527905       6                     NULL   NULL
2      459 -405612269    NULL 52a9ea8b534b2b0b5000575f 459001
3      988 1665303163    NULL                     NULL   NULL
4      459 -405626089    NULL 52a9ec00b73cbf0b210057e9 459001
5      459  816094026    NULL                     NULL   NULL
```